# Calling a function with call_user_func

Tags: php, function

I am struggling with calling a function with **call_user_func**!

I want to call the function by `$application->performAction('user', 'create')`;

**Application.php**:

```
<?php

class Application
{
    public $controllers = [];

    public function __construct($controllers)
    {
        array_push($this->controllers, $controllers);
    }

    public function performAction($model, $action)
    {
        call_user_func($this->controllers[$model], $action);
    }
}
```

**UserController.php**:

```
<?php

require './models/User.php';

class UserController
{
    public function create()
    {
        
    }

    ...
}
```

**index.php**:

```
<?php

require_once './core/Application.php';

require_once './controllers/UserController.php';

...

$controllers = [
    'user' => new UserController(),
    
    ...
];

$application = new Application($controllers);

$application->performAction('user', 'create');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making 2 serious mistakes in your code.

1. With array_push you add an array to an array and get a 2-dimensional array. This is not necessary. The following is sufficient:

   $this->controllers = $controllers;
2. call_user_func expects a callable function as the first parameter. For classes, an array must be taken as the first parameter.

You don't even need call_user_func to call a method. I added an alternative as a comment.
I think this can also be understood better. Have expanded your code to better show it all.

```
<?php
class UserController
{
    public function create($par)
    {
      var_dump('create from '.__CLASS__.' with('.$par.')');   
    }
}

class Application
{
    public $controllers = [];

    public function __construct(array $controllers)
    {
        $this->controllers = $controllers;
    }

    public function performAction($model, $action)
    {
        call_user_func([$this->controllers[$model],$action],"par_1");
        //$this->controllers[$model]->$action("par_1");
    }
}

$controllers = [
    'user' => new UserController(),
];

$application = new Application($controllers);

$application->performAction('user', 'create');
//output: string(38) "create from UserController with(par_1)"
```

[Try the second variant yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/630f5d28e7278b4f59eff8deb7447d58a8292da1). Call_user_func() is blocked in the PHP sandbox.